# Custom build Type not working on androidTest building

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

Hi i am trying to build a androidTest APK based on a flavour and a custom build type i have defined below:

```
 productFlavors {
    FlavourOne {
        applicationIdSuffix ".live"
        buildConfigField 'String', 'SERVER_BASE_URL', '"http://live.com"'

    }
    FlavourTwo {
        applicationIdSuffix ".demo"
        buildConfigField 'String', 'SERVER_BASE_URL', '"http://demo.com"'
    }
```

}

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            // shrink code (remove unused classes and methods) - note that it falls back to experimental shrinker for Instant Run
            shrinkResources false // don't strip unused res files
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro', 'proguard-rules-debug.pro'
            testProguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules-test.pro'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true // shrink code (remove unused classes and methods)
            shrinkResources false // don't strip unused res files
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debugDemo {
            applicationIdSuffix '.demo'
            versionNameSuffix '-DEMO'
            minifyEnabled false
            // shrink code (remove unused classes and methods) - note that it falls back to experimental shrinker for Instant Run
            shrinkResources false // don't strip unused res files
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro', 'proguard-rules-debug.pro'
            testProguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules-test.pro'
        }
        demo {
            applicationIdSuffix '.demo'
            versionNameSuffix '-DEMO'
            minifyEnabled true // shrink code (remove unused classes and methods)
            shrinkResources false // don't strip unused res files
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
```

When i run `gradlew assembleFlavourOneDebugDemoAndroidTest`  i get an error straight away saying

```
Task 'assembleFlavourOneDebugDemoAndroidTest' not found in root project 'MyProject'.
```

It works fine if i omit my custom buildType and just do `assembleFlavourOneAndroidTest` and it works. It also works if do `assembleFlavourOneDebugANdroidTest` only...

Comment: Can you post a minimal project with that setup in github and share the link?

Comment: Try to avoid capital letters in the buildtypes name. Use debugdemo instead of debugDemo.

Comment: @jonney accept the answer, thanks

Comment: None of the answers actually worked but I instead just added an if condition in the debug build type to say that if you passed a demo debug property. Prefix the app id and name

Comment: @jonney then, there is propably other issue than this one. Anyway I have tested my solution and its working.

Comment: I had similar problem and its only works with buildType debug. Try assembleFlavourOneDebugAndroidTest

Comment: @SergioCT read my answer. It actually solves the problem.

Comment: @kebab actually no it doesn't solve the issue. What if I wanna build a debug build type after all? Or add another build type and wanna build that? Your code won't work as it hard codes it to just work for one build type.

Comment: @jonney then you should create another issue which corresponds with what you just said. Title stands for one custom build type and not multiple types.

Answer (score 6):

According to the documentation only ***one*** Build Type is tested. By default it is the ***debug*** Build Type, but this can be reconfigured with:

```
android {
    testBuildType "demo" 
}
```

and your gradle task after sync should look like this:

```
./gradlew assembleFlavourOneDemoAndroidTest
```

and be careful there will be **NO** debug as you pointed out in your description at the end.

> assembleFlavourOne<strike>Debug</strike>DemoAndroidTest

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar problem,
I need **debug** build type when develop,
**debugMinify** build type when run androidTest on pipeline or assembleAPK

so follow bellow code ,
You can run androidTest on debug type when develop
and when you run assemble APK command , testBuildType will be changed

```
android{
   buildTypes{
      release{}
      debug{}
      debugMinify{}
   }
   testBuildType getCurrentVariant()
}

def getCurrentVariant() {
    Gradle gradle = getGradle()
    String tskReqStr = gradle.getStartParameter().getTaskRequests().toString()
    println(tskReqStr)

    if (tskReqStr.contains("assemble") && tskReqStr.contains("DebugMinify")) {
        print("buidType: debugMinify")
        return "debugMinify"
    } else {
        print("buidType: debug")
        return "debug"
    }
}
```

and

```
gradlew assembleDevelopDebugMinify 
gradlew assembleDevelopDebugMinifyAndroidTest

[DefaultTaskExecutionRequest{args=[assembleDevelopDebugMinify],projectPath='null'}]

buidType: debugMinify
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume some declarations lack the `initWith` instruction -

because any test build rigidly depends on `initWith debug`.

When using `initWith release`, no test tasks are generated.

```
debugDemo {
    initWith debug
    ...
}
```

> The `initWith` property allows you to copy configurations from other build types, then configure only the settings you want to change.

Comment: What does initWith  do?

Comment: @jonney it does what is says. see the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants).

Comment: That did not work. It still complained that the task assembleFlavourOneDebugDemoAndroidTest  is not found in the root project

Comment: @jonney when switching the build-type to `debugDemo` in Android Studio and then hitting the "run tests" button, it should show the correct task name in the output window. also in the Gradle window, all the tasks are being listed there, albeit nested in groups. often one has to prepend the module name ...before the task name (depending on the project layout).

Comment: the configuration is in general strange ... what are `testProguardFiles` good for? and why are those `applicationIdSuffix` being defined for the build-types and flavors? maybe get rid of all that useless clutter and start with a minimal configuration. there are several configurations which make no sense.